# Degree of irreducible polynomial involving Primitive root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The following question was asked in quiz of Field Theory ( now over ) and I am not sure about the answer of this question.

> If z is a primitive 7th root of unity what is the degree of irreducible
> polynomial over Q of $ z+ z^{-1}$?

I got the answer as 49 : let $x =z+ 1/z$ , $xz=z^2 +1$ Now, taking power 7 and LHS is devoid of z but RHS is $2+ 7( z^5 + 3z^3 + 5z + 5z^6 +3z^4+z^2)$ which cannot be removed of z if power is taken less than 7 as root is primitive.

So, I got the answer 49.

Am I right? If not kindly give the right solution.

Comment: I’m afraid I really don’t understand your reasoning. However, note that $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is a subextension of $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ (which has degree $6$) so the degree of the minimal polynomial of $x$ must divide $6$.

Comment: @mindlack the reasoning is that Irreducible polynomial is smallest degree polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ (say f(x) )such that  z + $z^{-1}$is a root of f(x). So, I let x equals to that root which is $z +z^{-1}$ and tried to find a polynomial(minimal degrree) in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ whose root is x. I hope it is fine?

Comment: @Mindlack Can you please reply me?

Comment: That’s a reasonable approach. However, I’m not sure you can remove all the $z$ from $z^2+1=zx$ so as to end up with a nonzero rational polynomial $f$ such that $f(x)=0$. Note, as per my previous comment, that $[\mathbb{Q}(x):\mathbb{Q}] | 6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** use that $\mathbf{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\xi_7)/\Bbb Q) \simeq \Bbb Z_6$.

> Since the extension is cyclic, there is exactly one subextension for each divisor of $6$, and we also know that $\omega := \xi_7 + \xi_7^{-1} \not \in \Bbb Q$. So, we are left to decide whether $\Bbb Q(\xi_7+\xi_7^{-1}) / \Bbb Q$ has order $2,3$ or $6$.

**Hint:** consider the map $\sigma  \colon \Bbb Q(\xi_7)/\Bbb Q \to \Bbb Q(\xi_7)/\Bbb Q$ defined by $\xi_7 \mapsto \xi_7^{-1}$.

> This map fixes $\omega$ an has order $2$ (because $\xi_7 \neq \xi_7^{-1}$). Hence $\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q$ is a subextension of the fixed field of $\langle \sigma\rangle$, which has order $3$ and thus $\Bbb Q(\omega)/ \Bbb Q$ is actually cubic.

Comment: In 2nd Hint "This map fixes ω" you haven't defined $\omega$?

Comment: It's defined above, in the first hint.

Comment: Can you also tell why doesn't the argument by which I got order =49 doesn't makes any sense?

Comment: The proposed polynomial in the OP does not have degree 49 nor have you shown that it is irreducible (but I have never claimed anything didn't make sense.)

Comment: Also, le lhs has an $x^7$ which may not lie in $\mathbb Q$, it is not "devoid of $z$".